# Error in facebook integration in react js

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-login

I have tried  to integrate the facebook login in my sample website using reactjs(localhost).

1. I created the APP (APP ID) in facebook developer console
2. I installed the package react-facebook-login-component.
3. Here is the some code to access the facebook

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FacebookLogin } from 'react-facebook-login-component';

const $ = window.$;

class FacebookLoginData extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          facebookRes:{},
          user : {},
          addUserNameModal:false,
          sociallogin :{}
        }
    }

    /*************
    facebook login
    *************/
    responseFacebook(response){
      this.props
      .facebookLoginData({
        variables:{
           email : response.email,
           name : response.name,
           facebookid : response.id,
           profilepic : response.picture.data.url
        }
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
          var user = data.facebookLogin;
          this.setState({user});

          if(user){
              localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("errors..in facebook.."+JSON.stringify(error))
      })
    }

    render(){
    
      return(
        <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        // Social ID --- APP ID
        <FacebookLogin socialId="*************" 
          language="en_US"
          scope="public_profile, email"
          xfbml={true}
          responseHandler={this.responseFacebook.bind(this)}
          fields="name,email,picture.height(2048)"
          version="v2.5"
          class="fbbutton"
          buttonText=" FACEBOOK"/>

          
          </div>
        )
      }
  }

 
  export default FacebookLoginData;
```

4. After these steps, i am getting this error

**Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**

5. But i can't find the error where it is.

Comment: Error says that you've to add your domain url in the app's domains.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the URL from which you are going to access Facebook Login API.

Go to your App Settings page from https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Then add **your App Domain**. Something like this

[image]

You also need to add the Site URL here

```
Settings -> Basic -> Website -> Site URL
```

[image]

**If you are testing it on your local, then add localhost in the app domain and http://localhost in the Site URL.**

Comment: where can i  place the my site URL. There are three
1.APP Domain
2.Privacy Policy URL
3.Terms of Service URL

Comment: Thank you @ GSSwain

Answer (score 1):

You should place your domain url in: Site URL
[image]

Comment: Thank you @ Pavan kumar Dasireddy